# How to go about multiple dynamic components in the same modal in angular 2?

Tags: angular

I'm making a platform where a user can choose from a set of input forms. The content and submit handling (API-call etc) of each form is different, but the user interface surrounding it is the same: it should open in a modal window, and it has a floating bottom bar with an auto-save message and a submit button.

Of course I want to re-use my modal logic. There's a number of things I've already run into. How do I go about...

- making a component (modal) that can have any of a set of components (form-x, form-y, ...) as its content (dynamically opened by a button somewhere)
- having a shared submit button and maybe some other shared form methods that are used by all forms, but then also call a custom submit method for the specific form
- calling some sort of a 'close' method on the parent modal

I've tried a lot of things, but I don't think I really understand the architectural best practice of angular 2 for this sort of case. Maybe I'm getting the approach all wrong, so please help :)

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea :

You could have a component and put your forms inside it

```
<modalForm (submit)="f.submit" [url]="someUrl">
    <myForm #f><myForm>
</modalForm>
```

Then in the `modalForm` you'd have

```
<div>
   <button class="closeBtn" (click)="close()">X</submit>
   <ng-content ></ng-content>
   <button class="fakeSubmitBtn" (click)="emitter.next()">Submit</submit>

</div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/bCUSVBwBskiI353wN1PO?p=preview

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <my-parent (submit)="c.submit()">
       <my-sub #c></my-sub>
    </my-parent>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'my-parent',
  template: `
    <div>
       <ng-content #f></ng-content>
       <button (click)="submit.emit(true)">CLICK</button>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class Parent {
  name:string;
  @Output() submit = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }

}


@Component({
  selector: 'my-sub',
  template: `
    <h1>{{name}}</h1>
  `,
})
export class Sub {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'SUBSUB'
  }
  submit(){
    console.log('receives');
    this.name='submitted';
  }
}
```

I'm kind of interested in other answers though, I'm sure there are better ways.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like we have similar requirements, we have a page that has several different dialogs so I'll share what we are doing, hopefully it will be useful.

We are using the dialog from [PrimeNG](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dialog) and providing the content (like the previous answer from @Ced).

```
<p-dialog [(visible)]="showFormX" header="Form X" modal="true">
    <app-form-x (cancelled)="showFormX = false">
    </app-form-x>
</p-dialog>
```

FormX component would contain the dialog content

```
<form #formX="ngModel" (ngSubmit)="save($event)">
    // form fields here as required

    <app-button-bar>
        // see below for details..
    </app-button-bar>

</form>

@Component({
selector: 'app-form-x',
..
})
export class FormXComponent {

    @Output() cancelled: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    @Output() saved: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    ...
    cancel($event) {
       this.cancelled.emit($event);
    }

    save($event){
        //.. call the http service to save ..           
        this.saved.emit($event);
    }
}
```

We also have a component to help us with buttons at the bottom of each dialog.

Most of our dialogs want the Save/Cancel buttons on the right.
And optionally extra buttons on the left, in this case we have a print option for this form.

```
<app-button-bar>
    <app-left-buttons>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="print()">
            <i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print
        </button>
    </app-left-buttons>

    <app-right-buttons>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!formX.valid">
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Save
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="cancel$event)">
            <i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cancel
        </button>
    </app-right-buttons>
</app-button-bar>
```